# aiogram, type object 'Dispatcher' has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python

here is the code of my program:

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

# Создаем экземпляр бота и диспатчера
bot = Bot('6912103058:AAGiUjg0zD4U6jbYi1upfQN-VQgk8sorRT4')
dp = Dispatcher

# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    # Отправляем сообщение пользователю
    await message.reply('Привет!')

# Обработчик текстовых сообщений
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def text_handler(message: types.Message):
    # Отправляем сообщение пользователю
    await message.reply('Я получил сообщение: ' + message.text)

# Запускаем бота
asyncio.run(dp.start_polling())
```

I am working with the aiogram 3.3.0 library and it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\chatbot\chatbot\bot_tg.py", line 10, in 
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Dispatcher' has no attribute 'message_handler'

I created a chat bot on the aiogram library, reinstalled the aiogram, deleted the conflicting telegram-bot library, but I still get this error, please who can help